# NameError: name not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze some data, my code is as follows:

```
for line in h:

    if line_cnt in start_x:
        recording_scores = True
        temp_i = start_x.index(line_cnt)
        score_acc = [0, 0, 0]
        codon_id = remainder_x[temp_i]
        temp_z = line.split()
        temp_score = float(temp_z[1])  
        score_acc[codon_id] += temp_score
        codon_id = (codon_id + 1) % 3 

    if temp_i>0 and line_cnt == end_x[temp_i]:
        score_x0[temp_i] = score_acc[0] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        score_x1[temp_i] = score_acc[1] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        score_x2[temp_i] = score_acc[2] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        temp_i = -1
        recording_scores = False
```

I keep getting an error message saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CRECDR_analysis.py", line 79, in <module>
    if temp_i>0 and line_cnt == end_x[temp_i]:
NameError: name 'temp_i' is not defined
CRE_CDR.pbs.e4524341 (END)
```

I thought I defined temp_i in the first if statement, but does the definition not carry over to the second if statement? Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Well, what if `line_cnt in start_x` is false?

Answer (score 0):

As Morgan pointed out, you don't define `temp_i` or `line_cnt` if you don't go into the first loop. I don't know what you want to do exactly, but you probably meant to do this if you only meant to test the second condition if the first was true.

```
for line in h:

    if line_cnt in start_x:
        recording_scores = True
        temp_i = start_x.index(line_cnt)
        score_acc = [0, 0, 0]
        codon_id = remainder_x[temp_i]
        temp_z = line.split()
        temp_score = float(temp_z[1])  
        score_acc[codon_id] += temp_score
        codon_id = (codon_id + 1) % 3 

        if temp_i>0 and line_cnt == end_x[temp_i]:
            score_x0[temp_i] = score_acc[0] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
            score_x1[temp_i] = score_acc[1] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
            score_x2[temp_i] = score_acc[2] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
            temp_i = -1
            recording_scores = False
```

Otherwise, you would want to define `temp_i` and `line_cnt` in an else statement as such:
    for line in h:

```
    if line_cnt in start_x:
        recording_scores = True
        temp_i = start_x.index(line_cnt)
        score_acc = [0, 0, 0]
        codon_id = remainder_x[temp_i]
        temp_z = line.split()
        temp_score = float(temp_z[1])  
        score_acc[codon_id] += temp_score
        codon_id = (codon_id + 1) % 3 
    else:
        temp_i = 0
        line_cnt = foo

    if temp_i>0 and line_cnt == end_x[temp_i]:
        score_x0[temp_i] = score_acc[0] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        score_x1[temp_i] = score_acc[1] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        score_x2[temp_i] = score_acc[2] / ((end_x[temp_i] - start_x[temp_i] + 1) / 3)
        temp_i = -1
        recording_scores = False
```

Comment: No. I moved the second if into the first if, because I assumed you only meant to test the second condition if the first was true.